# Replication of Table?

Tags: sql-server, replication

Goal:
*Same database to have 2 similiar table named test1 an test2.
*Table test2 is only used for query (read only) and table test1 is only used for command (delete, create and update).

Background:
*Test2 is a replication of Test1 (any changes in test1 should update in table test2 in realtime).

Problem:
Is it possibly to make a replication of a table in the same database in SQL server?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you define what "realtime" means in terms of allowable latency? SQL Server transactional replication is asynchronous and can have many factors that affect latency, but I would generally set expectations that "minutes" of latency should be the default expectation

Comment: What's the point of this setup? I hope that it is not to improve performance by separating reads and writes to different tables in the same database, because the result will likely be the opposite.